# not able to insert script into asp page using codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have a simple `gridview` control in my asp.net/c# page I want to show a message that displays "delete successful" on the deletion of my row I tried using this but it has no effect.

My code is this..

```
script = string.Format(@"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully deleted');</script>");
if (Page != null && !Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", script);
}
```

Can anyone help me out please, I am new to this..
Thaks
-Vishu

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page , typeof(Page) , Guid.NewGuid().ToString() , "alert('Successfully deleted');" , true);
```

Hope it may work

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**CODE**:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "popup();", true);
```

where **popup()** is a javascript function.

**SCRIPT**:

```
function popup() {
    $("#popupdiv").fadeIn('slow');
 }
```

**popupdiv** is the Id of the div which u can design as per your requirements

Comment: JQuery is not tagged and this changes what he was trying to do.

Comment: `$("#popupdiv").fadeIn('slow');` is jQuery.